# MySQLi and Phalanger

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, mysqli, phalanger

I am trying to port 3 large php-projects into C# and thought Phalanger is a nice possibility to take it step by step instead of re-writing it all from scratch.

But I ran in to a problem. The projects are using mysqli, and I don't know how to make this work with Phalanger. Currently, my project casts an exception when I call the mysqli_init()-method.

I have googled it for hours and can't seem to find any info about it.

Does anyone know how I should solve this?
Help is much appreciated =)

/Mattias

Answer (score 3):

Just found out that mysqli is yet to be implemented. Phalanger 3.0 do not support mysqli.